# How can I access the value of JSON which has Array in Object?

Tags: php, arrays, json, jsondecoder

I wish to know an simple way to access the value inside following JSON, which owns an Array.
I am codeing in PHP:

```
<?php

$json = '{"flight": "7800", "city": "New York", "time":[{"Houston":"17:34","Los Angles":"21:23"}]}';   

$str = json_decode($json);
echo $str->city;   // New York
//echo $str->time->Houston;    // How can I access the valus of Houston:  17:34  

?>
```

Comment: `$str->time[0]->Houston`

Comment: nice! @nice_dev but how to access "Los Angles"? $str->time[1]->"Los Angles" failed.

Comment: It will be `echo $str->time[0]->{'Los Angles'};`

Answer (score 1):

Decode the Json-String as assoc array:

```php
$json = '{"flight": "7800", "city": "New York", "time":[{"Houston":"17:34","Los Angeles":"21:23"}]}';
   
$flight = json_decode($json, true);// You get associative array in this case

echo "<br>" . $flight['city'];   // New York
echo "<br>" . $flight['time'][0]['Houston'];
echo "<br>" . $flight['time'][0]['Los Angeles'];
```